# I am unable to figure out why data is not being added to my database with my JS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to NodeJS and Express. I have been trying to use Node and Express and MongoDB to create a server and APIs that add data to the database. I am trying to write this in ESmodules syntax to write JS. I think there is something wrong with the way I have defined a MongoDB model, or with the the way I have imported it in different pages. This code is based on the BezKoder website. While I was able to implement the code in the way it was given in the website using CommonJS, I wanted to try to do the same with ESmodules. Everything seems fine expect no data is being added to the DB. when I try to print the attributes of the data that is to be added, it prints out undefined. Please help me identify my mistake.
Thank you

I tried changing the way I wrote the model, tried using arrow functions instead of normal functions, tried to print the model instance using console.log, I also tried to check if I have imported things correctly. the pages are,

Server.js

```
import express,{json,urlencoded} from 'express';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import db from './App/Models/index.js'
import {router} from './App/Routes/patient.signup.routes.js'

const app = express()
var corurl = {original: "http://localhost:8082"}

app.use(cors(corurl))
app.use(json())
app.use(urlencoded({extended: true }))

// Connection //
db.mongoose.connect(db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => {
    console.log("Database connected.")
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log("Cannot connected to Database.", err)
    process.exit()
})

/* REQUESTS and ROUTES */

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({Message:"Hello, Welcome to Wearable."})
})

app.use('/Patientsignup', router);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}.`);
});
```

db.config.js

```
const url = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/Server";
export {url}
```

patient.controller.js

```
import db from '../Models/index.js'

const entry = db.patientsignup

function create(req,res){
    if(!req.body.Name){
        res.status(400).send({Message: "Content is empty, please rectify."})
    }

    const patient = new entry({
        Name: req.body.namex,
        MobileNumber: req.body.mobileNumber,
        Gender: req.body.gender
    })

    console.log(patient)
    console.debug(console.error())
    console.debug(patient.mobile_number)

    patient
    .save(patient)
    .then(Data =>{
        res.send(Data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Patient."
        });
    })
}

export {create}
```

index.js

```
import { url } from "../Config/db.config.js";
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import PatientSignup from './patient.signup.model.js';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const db = {}
db.mongoose = mongoose
db.url = url
db.patientsignup = PatientSignup(mongoose)

export default db;
```

patient.signup.model.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    mobile_number: Number,
    gender: String,
})

export default PatientSignup => {
    const patient = PatientSignup.model("PatientSignup", schema)
    return patient
}
```

patient.signup.routes.js

```
import {create} from '../Controllers/patient.controller.js'
import {Router as routerman} from 'express'

const router = routerman()
router.post("/",create)


export {router}
```

[image: This is my file structure]

Comment: Some issues are worrying. `original: "http://localhost:8082"` should likely be `origin: "http://localhost:8082"`. Spelling: `req.body.Name` vs `req.body.namex`; `mobile.number` vs `MobileNumber`;

Comment: thank you. I swear every time my code faulters its because of a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've made good progress in converting your code to ES modules syntax. However, I can see a few issues in your code that might be causing the problem you described. Let's go through them:

**Property Naming Mismatch:** In your patient.controller.js file, you're trying to access properties like req.body.namex and req.body.mobileNumber, but your schema defines properties as name, mobile_number, and gender. Make sure to use the correct property names from the schema in your controller.

**Incorrect Model Access:** In your db.index.js file, you're trying to access the PatientSignup model using db.patientsignup = PatientSignup(mongoose). However, you should directly import the PatientSignup model from the patient.signup.model.js file and use it as the model.

Here's how you can update these parts of your code:

**patient.controller.js:**

```
import db from '../Models/index.js'

const entry = db.patientsignup

function create(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.name || !req.body.mobile_number || !req.body.gender) {
        return res.status(400).send({ Message: "Content is empty, please rectify." })
    }

    const patient = new entry({
        name: req.body.name,
        mobile_number: req.body.mobile_number,
        gender: req.body.gender
    })

    patient
        .save() // no need to pass argument here as mongoose takes care of it 
        .then(Data => {
            res.send(Data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Patient."
            });
        })
}

export { create }
```

**index.js:**

```
import { url } from "../Config/db.config.js";
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import PatientSignup from './patient.signup.model.js';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Database connected.")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Cannot connect to Database.", err)
        process.exit()
    });

const db = {}
db.mongoose = mongoose
db.patientsignup = PatientSignup

export default db;
```

With these changes, the property names should match the schema, and you're directly importing and using the PatientSignup model in your index.js file.

Make sure to also check the rest of your code for any other naming mismatches or errors. If you're still encountering issues, you might consider adding more logging to track the flow of data and identify where the problem might be occurring.

Comment: thank you for the answer. While correcting the naming errors solved my problem, directly importing model gave me an error. If I directly import it, it is not a constructor anymore and thus throws an error. Am I missing something?